# Create directory using SAP BODS script?

Tags: directory, business-objects, sap-data-services

How does one create directories in a given path on Windows using SAP Business Objects Designer 4.2 Script?

I got a **Script** with path that I'd like to create **if it does not exist**:

```
$My_Path = '\\\\localsrv\\source data\\post\\november'
```

My current network location only cosists of:

```
\\localsrv\source data\
```

And I would like to create subdirectories `post` and `post\november` within that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Script** we need to use an `exec()` function which sends a command to operating system for execution. It takes below arguments:

```
exec(
  <command file> -- for example cmd or bat
  <parameter_list> -- values to pass as arguments to the command line
  <flag> -- defines action upon error or nonzero return code
)
```

That said, simply use `cmd` and `md` command to create directories with subdirectories on Windows and combine it with `if not exists` to skip trying to make a directory when it already exists.

Script will look like:

```
$My_Path = '\\\\localsrv\\source data\\post\\november'
exec('cmd', 'if not exists "[$My_Path]" md "[$My_Path]"');
```